# Generating SSL key for Dovecot and Postfix

Tags: ssl, postfix, email-server, dovecot

Following this tutorial:
https://www.vultr.com/docs/simple-mailserver-postfix-dovecot-sieve-debian

Trying to create a self-signed SSL certificate for testing purposes for my mail server, using code:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -sha512 -x509 -days 365 -nodes -keyout /etc/dovecot/private/mykey.key -out /etc/dovecot/mycert.pem
```

Now, modifying Postfix and Dovecot config files. What I don't understand is how this code:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/dovecot/private/mykey.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/dovecot/private/mycert.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

And this code:

```
ssl = yes
ssl_key = /etc/dovecot/private/mykey.pem
ssl_cert = /etc/dovecot/private/mycert.pem
```

suppose to work? First of all there is only one file created - `/etc/dovecot/private/mykey.key`.

May be someone can explain what files does one suppose to get after running `openssl` command - PEM of KEY file?

**EDIT**: I understood that the result of this command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -sha512 -x509 -days 365 -nodes -keyout /etc/dovecot/private/mykey.key -out /etc/dovecot/mycert.pem
```

should be 2 files generated - `mykey.pem` (unsigned key) and `mycert.pem` (self-signed certificate), but it is not happening. I have done it in different way:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -key key.pem -in csr.pem -out certificate.pem
```

But curious why is this shortcut-code not working? Where is the syntax mistake?

Comment: Both. But you didn't do your homework: howtos describing the self-signed certificate creation are widespread all over the internet. *google://openssl self-signed certificate*.

Comment: I was curious if the command ran successfully, since I've got only `mykey.key`

Comment: Hopefully silly question - you do realise the certificate file is being written to a different directory (/etc/dovecot) than the key file (/etc/dovecot/private), right?

Comment: @andytech Oh... OH!!!! And this is what happens when you look at the thing for too long.. you misses the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments from @drookie and @andytech helped me to solve the issue. There were no errors, just lack of understanding and attention.

After searching for answer even more, I found a good article about SSL-key generation: https://msol.io/blog/tech/create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-with-openssl/

Regarding the `.pem` absence, I have missed that the certificate is generated into `/etc/dovecot/cert.pem` and **not** into `/etc/dovecto/private/cert.pem`.

Comment: just say the article is wrong that you linked!

Comment: jesus christ man! what a waste of time!!! not only is the path wrong, the file format of the file is wrong too! it is `mykey.key` not `mykey.pem`